# My angular rxjs combineLatest is not propagating the types to the pipe operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive

The IDE properly identifies the two objects in the combineLatest operator as an **IStory[]** and **string** respectively. Once I pipe and destructure the content, the IDE identifies both elements as storys:unknown & selectedId:unknown. The IDE crashes with type errors when I run *ng start*

The code combines an Array and a single string element and is filtered to return the IStory with a matching id value and assign it to an Observerable.

```
activeStory$:Observable<IStory> = combineLatest([          
        this.backend.stories$,  //array of IStory                               
        this.backend.selectedIdAction$       // a text string                  
    ]).pipe(                                                   
        map(([storys,selectedId]) =>     //array destructuring                       
          storys.filter(story => story.id === selectedId)      
      ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not resolve the type mismatch, but after testing the filter function on MDN with some dummy code, I realized I was returning an array.
**Array** [Object { name: "spray", id: "asdf" }]
The IDE was complaining about assigning an `Array<IStory>` to an `IStory` despite not recognizing the destructured elements. My working solution was to take index zero:

`storys.filter(story => story.id === selectedId)[0]`